# obtaining model matrix using pyopengl

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl, coordinate-transformation

I am trying to obtain the rotation matrix and translation matrix in a 3x4 matrix form using pyopengl in python. I found out from this link [here](http://3dengine.org/Modelview_matrix) that the rotation and translation matrix can be obtained from:

```
model = glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
```

I know that this is actually the modelview matrix and not the model matrix but I read in some post that this only work if I call glLoadIdentity() before getting the modelview matrix for eg.:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadIdentity()
model = glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
```

This is my sample code:

```
meshes = pywavefront.Wavefront("sample.obj") #3D model file goes here

#Get current directory
directory = os.getcwd() + "/result/" + filename 

#Create directory if does not exist
try:
    os.makedirs(directory)
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise

counter = 1
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
gl.glPushMatrix()
glLoadIdentity()
model1 = glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
print("Matrix 1: ")
print(model1) #should print identity matrix

glRotatef(15, 1, 0, 0)
glTranslatef(0.0, -4, -10)
glRotatef(60, 0, 1, 0)
model2 = glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
print("Matrix 2: ")
print(model2)
meshes.draw()
pygame.image.save(screen, directory+"/"+filename+"_"+str(counter)+".jpg")
counter += 1
gl.glPopMatrix()

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
gl.glPushMatrix()
glLoadIdentity()
model3 = glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
print("Matrix 3: ")
print(model3) #should print identity matrix

glRotatef(15, 1, 0, 0)
glTranslatef(0.0, -2.2, -10)
glRotatef(90, 0, 1, 0)
model4 = glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
print("Matrix 4: ")
print(model4)
meshes.draw()
pygame.image.save(screen, directory+"/"+filename+"_"+str(counter)+".jpg")
counter += 1
gl.glPopMatrix()
```

This is the output of the above code:

```
Matrix 1: 
[[ 1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]]
Matrix 2: 
[[  0.49999997   0.22414388  -0.83651632   0.        ]
 [  0.           0.96592581   0.25881904   0.        ]
 [  0.86602545  -0.12940951   0.48296288   0.        ]
 [  0.          -1.2755127  -10.6945343    1.        ]]
Matrix 3: 
[[ 1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]]
Matrix 4: 
[[ -4.37113883e-08   2.58819044e-01  -9.65925813e-01  -0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   9.65925813e-01   2.58819044e-01   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.00000000e+00   1.13133396e-08  -4.22219593e-08   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   4.63153839e-01  -1.02286596e+01   1.00000000e+00]]
```

The problem is the matrix obtained looks weird. The last row should be [0,0,0,1] but instead I got some values in it. I actually ran similar code in c++ opengl and the last row was always [0,0,0,1] but not for pyopengl.

My goal is to only obtain rotation and translation matrix in 3x4 matrix form and my question is can I just take the first 3 rows as is and ignore the last row despite it having values? eg.:

```
Matrix 2: 
[[  0.49999997   0.22414388  -0.83651632   0.        ]
[  0.           0.96592581   0.25881904   0.        ]
[  0.86602545  -0.12940951   0.48296288   0.        ]
```

even if doing this, it looks wrong because I translate it using glTranslatef(0.0, -4, -10) but the translation column (the 4th column on the right) is showing [0,0,0].

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks as if they are printed transposed. The last column is always [0,0,0,1].

Comment: @BDL I was thinking the same too. but then again, if so I still couldn't understand why the "Matrix 4" in the output has a negative value ie. -0.00000000e+00 in the first element of the 4th column

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks for the response. So meaning, I would just have to transpose the matrix with model2.transpose() right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fixed function pipeline operations (`glRotatef`, `glTranslatef`, ...) create matrices in column-major order. Because of that your output is transposed.

See [OpenGL 2.1 (API Specification); 2.11.2 Matrices; page 43](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec21.pdf):

> **LoadMatrix** takes a pointer to a 4 × 4 matrix stored in **column-major** order as 16 consecutive floating-point values ...
>
> (This differs from the standard row-major C ordering for matrix elements. If the standard ordering is used, all of the subsequent transformation equations are transposed, and the columns representing vectors become rows.)
>   The specified matrix replaces the current matrix with the one pointed to. **MultMatrix** takes the same type argument as **LoadMatrix**, but multiplies the current matrix by the one pointed to and replaces the current matrix with the product. If C is the current matrix and M is the matrix pointed to by **MultMatrix**’s argument, then the resulting current matrix, C', is
>
> ```
> C'  = C · M
> ```
>
> ....
>
> There are a variety of other commands that manipulate matrices. **Rotate**,
>   **Translate**, **Scale**, **Frustum**, and **Ortho** manipulate the current matrix. Each computes a matrix and then invokes **MultMatrix** with this matrix.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. Its really2 helpful. :)